# Sphinx autodoc not importing anything?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, numpydoc

I'm trying to use `sphinx` (in conjunction with `autodoc` and `numpydoc`) to document my module, but after the basic setup, running `make html` produces just the basic html with nothing from the docstrings included. I'm running Python 3.3, the outline of the project structure is as follows:

```
Kineticlib
|--docs
|  |--build
|  |--source
|  |  |--conf.py
|--src
|  |--kineticmulti
|  |  |--__init__.py
|  |  |--file1.py
|  |  |--file2.py
|--setup.py
```

`__init__.py` is empty, and in `conf.py` in the `docs/source` directory I've added `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))`

Running `make html` in the `docs` directory gives the following output:

```
sphinx-build -b html -d build/doctrees   source build/html
Running Sphinx v1.2.2
loading pickled environment... done
building [html]: targets for 0 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
looking for now-outdated files... none found
no targets are out of date.

Build finished. The HTML pages are in build/html.
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you run sphinx-apidoc in the docs/source directory?  This will generate the .rst files used to make the html.  From `man sphinx-apidoc`,

```
sphinx-apidoc [options] -o <outputdir> <sourcedir> [pathnames ...]
```

You'll need to include (at a minimum) the `outputdir` (where the .rst files will go, ./ should work) and the `sourcedir` which should point to your package (looks like ../../src/kineticmulti should work)

Comment: Yes, I forgot to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As it is being said you should do:

```
sphinx-apidoc [options] -o <outputdir> <sourcedir> [pathnames ...]
```

Sometime modifying your conf.py to import some source modules are also needed. As well as adding some docs to class in order to load its method docs (can be true only for private classed, but I've been stuck on that).